# where is the “Recently Used”,“In Active Adverts”, "Action Needed", "Shared" filtering based from facebook custom audience data?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

If you go to business manager of facebook, then go to the "All Audiences", then under the "Audiences" tab, you will see a "Filters" button right beside the "Create Audience" button. Now my question is, which part the json data being provided by the facebook apis should I based the data that I should pull out based from these filters ?

```
- Recently Used
- In Active Adverts
- Action Needed
- Shared
```

Because unlike the "ready" and "not ready" status, those four filters that I mentioned are not straight forward where I can just look for the numbers from the returned json data. so how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, not all of this information is available through the API.

However, if you take a look at the following doc, you can see some reelvant fields that may help:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-audience

Most likely you can use the field `operation_status` to look at whether an audience needs action.

For whether it's shared, take a look ad the edge `adaccounts` which will let you see the ad accounts this audience has been shared with.

For recently used, you'll probably have to look at the edge `ads` and review the status of the ads.

To save having to make multiple requests, you can take a look at field expansion in the Graph API, which will let you query for fields of objects in results using a single request:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#fieldexpansion

Comment: by the way, are we allowed to create "ALL" types of custom audiences and saved targeting via the "sandbox" ?, i'm aware that we cannot see the things via the business page nor in ad/power editor...but are we able to create them all in sandbox ?